# Pl/sql Executing procedures

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am totally new to PL/SQL.

```
create or replace procedure p1(a in customer.id%type,
b out  customer.name%type,
c out  customer.dept%type)
is
 begin
 select name,dept into b,c from customer where id=a;
  end;
```

Its created properly.
But I am not sure how to execute it.
EXEC p1(1);
But this is showing error.

Comment: what is the error? where are you executing it?

Comment: the procedure have 3 parameters, you can't call it with p1(1) (1 parameter)

Answer (score 2):

Your procedure has three parameters so you'd need to call it with three parameters.  In the case of `OUT` parameters, you need to pass in variables that will hold the values that are being returned by the procedure.

```
DECLARE
  l_id    customer.id%type := 1;
  l_name  customer.name%type;
  l_dept  customer.dept%type;
BEGIN
  p1( l_id, l_name, l_dept );
  <<do something with l_name and l_dept>>
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to execute a procedure.

1. From the SQL prompt.

   EXECUTE [or EXEC] procedure_name;
2. Within another procedure – simply use the procedure name.

   procedure_name;

the procedure have 3 parameters, you can't call it like `p1(1)` using just one parameter

in your case try something like this

```
DECLARE
  p_name        customer.name%type;
  p_department  customer.dept%type;
BEGIN
  p1(1, p_name, p_department);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Output parameters should be stored in variables.
Input, can be variables or directly given in between the ( )
Use dbms_output.put_line to easily show output in your IDE.

```
DECLARE
   p_name        customer.name%type;
   p_department  customer.dept%type;
   p_id          customer.id%type := 1;
BEGIN
   p1(p_id, p_name, p_department);
END;
```